# HTML select element - Custom default value? ( Cross-browser solution )

Tags: javascript, html, forms, cross-browser

How do I display a custom ( non-option ) text as default value of a select?

I would like to display a select tag saying: "Choose whatever",
but I don't want this string to appear in the list of options.

*In Your answer - if possible - please avoid overlapping elements, and other cheap solutions to keep up cross-browser support.*

Comment: It sounds like you want a `select` element to contain and not contain a default option with a certain value. Can you formulate the goal in a manner that does not sound that contradictory? And telling *why* you want that might help in understanding exactly *what* you are after.

Comment: Sure. I would like to display a hint, what to choose in this dropdown, but instead of labelling it visually outside, I'd like to do it insde the select element. For better understanding, I would like the element to actually contain this option, but the option to be hidden in the option list when the user focuses the select.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to hide an option when a `select` element is focused on (which seems to be the intent, as per the comments), the simplest way is to remove the first option when the `select` element is focused on. Assuming, for definiteness, that you want to do this for a single `select` element, which has `id=foo` assigned to it, this code would do the job:

window.onload = function() {
  document.getElementById('foo').onfocus = function() {
    this.removeChild(this.options[0]);
  };
}

This has some usability problems, though. The hint is lost forever when the use focuses on the element, and this is bad if the user is just moving around the form and might need the hint later when he actually wants to make the selection. (Fixing this by restoring it on blur is not that simple, since form submission, too, blurs the element.) And the hint isn’t available when the user is making the selection inside element, but this is inherit in the request. According to accessibility principles, controls should have labels, associated with them using the `label` element.

P.S. Although CSS has the `:focus` selector, you cannot effectively use CSS for the purpose, due to the specialties in implementations. A `select` element is typically implemented in a manner that is more or less immune to CSS.

Answer (score 2):

No need for `optgroup` or JavaScript:

```
<select>
  <option disabled selected>Choose whatever</option>
  <option>1</option>
</select>
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/odhLeeax/)

Comment: Although it's "'disabled'-colored" ( grayish ) it IS visible in the option list.

Comment: Yes - what harm will come of this, though? And if you intend to support mobile devices I don't recommend getting too hacky.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by showing the default option inside a `span` ie, as not a part of `select`.

**HTML:**

```
<span id="default_message">Choose whatever</span>
<select id="my_select">
    <option value="1">Option 1</option>  
    <option value="2">Option 2</option>
    <option value="3">Option 3</option>
</select>
```

**JQUERY :**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#my_select').prop("selectedIndex", -1);

    var offset = $('#my_select').offset();
    offset.top += 3;
    offset.left += 3;
    $('#default_message').offset(offset);

    $('#my_select').change(function() {
        if ($(this).prop("selectedIndex") != -1) {
            $('#default_message').hide();
        }
    });
});
```

And your **CSS :**

```
#default_message {
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    width: 120px;
    color: grey;
}
select {
    width: 150px;
}
```

You can also make the default option as `disabled`, then it will not be able to select, but it will be shown along with other options in the list.

```
<select id="my_select">
    <option value="1" selected disabled>Choose whatever</option> 
    <option value="1">Option 1</option>  
    <option value="2">Option 2</option>
    <option value="3">Option 3</option>
</select>
```

Comment: I upvote Your answer for the selected disabled attributes. However, I am still waiting for a solution without overlapping elements.

Comment: I know only these two options. May be someone else can help you :)

Comment: what do you mean by overlapping elements?

Answer (score 1):

Why not use an `<optgroup>`:

```
<select id="my_select">
    <optgroup label="choose whatever">
        <option value="1">Option 1</option>  
        <option value="2">Option 2</option>
        <option value="3">Option 3</option>
    </optgroup>
</select>
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/5Lsokzrg/).

The down-side is that the `<optgroup>`'s label is only visible upon opening the `<select>`, in preference of the (default, or) selected value being shown.

Using only HTML and CSS:

```
<select>
    <option disabled selected>Select something</option>
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>3</option>
    <option>4</option>
    <option>5</option>
</select>
```

With the CSS:

```
select:focus option:disabled {
    display: none;
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/odhLeeax/1/).

References:

- [`<optgroup>`](http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/optgroup).

Comment: Not actually what I am looking for. This will not make the select display the label of the optgroup before focusing it.
( Thank You for the demanding answer )

Comment: No, it won't; but to do that you'll have to manipulate the HTML. Either its display, with CSS, or the DOM itself, via JavaScript. The first you've stated is a "*cheap solution*" (and presumably unwanted), and the latter approach features no tag to your question. So you'll have to compromise somewhere.

Comment: I would gladly take a JS solution. I have added the tag as well.